# What does "broken wide open" mean?

Tags: meaning

> she’s broken wide open, raw.

Could you please tell me what's the meaning of "broken wide open"?

The full text is:

> She glances at Riley, whom she recognized the night before as a war
>   correspondent for the New York Times. She’s got the look. Not the look
>   of the hardened journalist who has necessarily grown a thick,
>   protective skin. She’s at the other end of the scale—**she’s broken wide
>   open, raw.** She wonders if Riley will ever be put back together again.
>   She can recognize PTSD when she sees it; she’s seen it before.

*An Unwanted Guest* by Shari Lopena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The metaphorical "protective shell" or "protective skin" is cracked open exposing what's inside.  There's a Humpty Dumpty allusion lurking under there. In cartoons, Humpty's [portrayed as an egg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9HtOIzvA8U).

**wide open** means "gaping" or completely open.

> It's snowing, and you left the front door wide open!